# Partial screen UIScrollView using AutoLayout / storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I want to have a scroll view taking up most of the screen with the bottom portion reserved for a stack view (for navigation). Something like this:

[image]

The contents are dynamic, hence the need for a scroll view in case there is a lot of text (or very large text for accessibility). I've tried several tutorials, all of which assume the scroll view consumes the whole screen (See *Resources* below). They basically just pin the scroll view edges to the content layout guide, then set equal widths to frame layout. Then they add contents to the "inner" UIView and make sure vertical constraints are satisfied. That's it.

In my scenario, when trying my best to adjust these tutorials to account for the stack view, I have issues like (1) no bounce effect and (2) infinite scrolling. Here are my constraints:

[image]

**Resources**

I've tried all of the following (and more):

- https://fluffy.es/scrollview-storyboard-xcode-11/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkoKquBuM4Y
- https://medium.com/@luisfmachado/uiscrollview-autolayout-on-a-storyboard-a-step-by-step-guide-15bd67ee79e9
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CHadfe_2G4

Answer (score 0):

First, a tip: during layout development, give your UI elements contrasting background colors... allows you to see the framing and makes it much easier to see what might be wrong.

Couple things look wrong with your constraints...

- it looks like you've constrained the `ContentView` Height to `600`. You don't want to do that, because you want the **contents** of that view to determine its height.
- your "last" subview of `ContentView` should have a bottom constraint -- which will control the height of that view.
- you have your StackView constrained to the bottom of `ContentView`, but `ContentView` is a *subview of the scroll view*. The StackView should be constrained to the bottom of the scroll view itself.

Take a look at this:

[image]

It should be very similar to what you posted (I guessed at your "TextFieldView" layout), with an added "Footer" label. Along with this example code, tapping on the "Next" button will add 20-lines of text to the Footer label so there's enough to need to scroll. Tapping the "Previous" button will switch back to the starting text.

```
class ScrollExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var footerLabel: UILabel!
    
    let demoString: String = "A multi-line label, with a large font, that we'll change on Button Taps -- so we can see the scrolling."
    
    @IBAction func nextTap(_ sender: Any) {
        // add 20 additional lines of text
        //  so we have enough content to scroll
        var s: String = ""
        for i in 1...20 {
            s += "\nAnother Line \(i)"
        }
        footerLabel.text = demoString + s
    }
    
    @IBAction func prevTap(_ sender: Any) {
        // reset to initial text
        footerLabel.text = demoString
    }

}
```

Here's the source for that Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="20037" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="vD2-wr-GKn">
    <device id="retina5_9" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="20020"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Scroll ExampleVC-->
        <scene sceneID="R32-dA-683">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="vD2-wr-GKn" customClass="ScrollExampleVC" customModule="CollectionStuff" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="nx6-KC-Ism">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="812"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KzK-Pa-O94">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44" width="375" height="663"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WqX-xW-fmK" userLabel="ContentView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="448.33333333333331"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Title Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="f8M-aa-ddy" userLabel="TitleLabel">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="20" width="311" height="28.666666666666671"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="SubTitle Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="L2d-7f-7wH" userLabel="SubTitleLabel">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="56.666666666666679" width="311" height="19.333333333333336"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="*US phone numbers only" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VID-c4-tBa" userLabel="PhoneReqLabel">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="84" width="311" height="19.333333333333329"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mR4-nY-BcV" userLabel="TextFieldView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="149.33333333333334" width="311" height="42"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" placeholder="Text Field" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="G17-qf-E4i" userLabel="TextField">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="4" y="4" width="303" height="34"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                                                    </textField>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="G17-qf-E4i" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="4" id="0u6-mq-UnJ"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="G17-qf-E4i" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="mR4-nY-BcV" secondAttribute="top" constant="4" id="2br-Cb-UCx"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="G17-qf-E4i" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="4" id="kBi-Tw-icx"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="G17-qf-E4i" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="mR4-nY-BcV" secondAttribute="leading" constant="4" id="sZG-wl-x72"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="A multi-line label, with a large font, that we'll change on Button Taps -- so we can see the scrolling." textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="diS-nP-pXL" userLabel="FooterLabel">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="237.33333333333331" width="311" height="191"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBlueColor"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="32"/>
                                                <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="f8M-aa-ddy" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="WqX-xW-fmK" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="14R-uH-nbh"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="diS-nP-pXL" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="WqX-xW-fmK" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="2z5-qB-GSx"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="VID-c4-tBa" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="4Bh-rc-Sf5"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="diS-nP-pXL" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="KZA-yZ-Y6g"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="VID-c4-tBa" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="WqX-xW-fmK" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="Khw-3T-o2e"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="L2d-7f-7wH" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="PBk-7v-nfi"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="mR4-nY-BcV" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="WqX-xW-fmK" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="WQD-gE-6Kw"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="diS-nP-pXL" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="XDP-fp-FDw"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="f8M-aa-ddy" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="bfM-nO-F64"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="mR4-nY-BcV" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="cMQ-1a-aj0"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="L2d-7f-7wH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="f8M-aa-ddy" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="cka-50-eUl"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="diS-nP-pXL" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="mR4-nY-BcV" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="46" id="d9t-1g-LCr"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="VID-c4-tBa" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="L2d-7f-7wH" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="dWJ-61-Ek9"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="mR4-nY-BcV" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VID-c4-tBa" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="46" id="kU5-od-Das"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="f8M-aa-ddy" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="WqX-xW-fmK" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="so0-TF-C6c"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="L2d-7f-7wH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="WqX-xW-fmK" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="xBR-f5-hHf"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="WqX-xW-fmK" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="QDf-KA-Txc" secondAttribute="bottom" id="1Mo-A1-Msg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="WqX-xW-fmK" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="QDf-KA-Txc" secondAttribute="top" id="L8o-hl-3zm"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="WqX-xW-fmK" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="QDf-KA-Txc" secondAttribute="trailing" id="O7A-8s-BNE"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="WqX-xW-fmK" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="QDf-KA-Txc" secondAttribute="leading" id="SWj-la-Ntb"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="WqX-xW-fmK" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="KjC-Gd-CAo" secondAttribute="width" id="sCr-he-FfC"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="QDf-KA-Txc"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="KjC-Gd-CAo"/>
                            </scrollView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="9" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4oF-wL-Hbo">
                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="707" width="311" height="69"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xwN-Fn-uU9">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="311" height="30"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="2.2250738585072014e-308" maxY="0.0"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Next"/>
                                        <connections>
                                            <action selector="nextTap:" destination="vD2-wr-GKn" eventType="touchUpInside" id="IXz-RV-DNc"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bWO-Bh-x6o">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="39" width="311" height="30"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="2.2250738585072014e-308" maxY="0.0"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Previous"/>
                                        <connections>
                                            <action selector="prevTap:" destination="vD2-wr-GKn" eventType="touchUpInside" id="FZu-Hz-IxW"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </button>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="OhM-Cg-QZj"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="4oF-wL-Hbo" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="2" id="7fX-cx-aPX"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="4oF-wL-Hbo" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="7qX-bn-CSx"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="KzK-Pa-O94" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" secondAttribute="leading" id="MSI-yJ-DoQ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="4oF-wL-Hbo" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="at1-ya-zpP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="KzK-Pa-O94" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" secondAttribute="trailing" id="cr8-5u-A2c"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="4oF-wL-Hbo" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="KzK-Pa-O94" secondAttribute="bottom" id="cuS-B5-BOt"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="KzK-Pa-O94" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" secondAttribute="top" id="hWo-Dt-XPd"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="footerLabel" destination="diS-nP-pXL" id="5tR-Jg-vl1"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="1GU-I7-lw5" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-789.60000000000002" y="214.28571428571431"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBlueColor">
            <color red="0.0" green="0.47843137254901963" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemYellowColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

and it looks like this when running:

[image] [image]